# Insert custom block before "col-left-first" ( customer account panel )

Tags: customer-account

Here's a screenshot to illustrate my question.
http://prntscr.com/ejyfd3

I want to insert a custom block `title.phtml` with a default title for all pages in Customer Account.

Where i trying `customer.xml`
http://prntscr.com/ejyl9l

Inside "root" reference, i put the `<block type="core/template" name="customer_section_title" template="customer/account/title.phtml"/>` but the block not show.

If i put the same code in "content" reference, it shows.

Any ideas?
I'm learning magento yet, not sure about some things

Comment: Here, i found a solution.... inspecting a select inside admin, when creating a new widget, i have noticed a value of the selected item. Then, i back to `customer.xml` and upated it;

[checkThisOut](http://prntscr.com/ejzr54)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Magento Stack Exchange. Feel free to post your solution as an answer to your own question, as this might help others in your situation. Also, could you please post your code as text rather than a screenshot. Thanks!

Comment: `<reference name="top.container">
            <block type="core/template" name="customer_section_title" template="customer/account/title.phtml"/>
</reference>`
i found the solution.